# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText

Tags: java, android-studio

I keep getting the same error. I know this is a dublicate question but none have helped. This app should output some data from CSV file with each click. I know the error means the textview is null. But the id matches on my xml and java file. Can someone please tell me what is I've wrong?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.decisionmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
```

I am getting error at

```
option.setText(node.getOption());
option2.setText(node.getOption2());
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView textView;
private Button bn1;
private Button bt2;
private TextView option1;
private TextView option2;
DecisionNode node;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

    bn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    DecisionMap crush;
    try {
        map = new DecisionMap(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (
            FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return;
    }
        node = map.entryPoint();

        textView.setText(node.getDescription());


        option1.setText(node.getOption());
        option2.setText(node.getOption2());
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1A2D30"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "textView"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "textView">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text= "textView">

    </TextView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:backgroundTint="#ACA248" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTint="#AEA343" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="259dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:background="#215023"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have seen those answers as well. Unfortunately it didn't help to spot the mistake in my code.

Comment: well option or option2 is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option1 and option2 are null because you never initialized them. All you need to do is this:

```
option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option1);
option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.option2);
option1.setText(node.getOption());
...
```